# Neo4J/Cypher Query assistance

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4jclient

I am doing some research into Graph Database Systems as part of POC to possibly move a system across to. I am really new to the concept and come from a RDBMS background.

I have a model (schema?) that looks like:

```
Person-[HAS_NAME {type:First|Middle|Last}]-Name
Person-[WAS_BORN_ON]-DateOfBirth
Person-[RESIDES_AT {type:Current|Previous}]-Address
```

I am able to store this data perfectly using Neo4J and Neo4JClient in a C# application.

Where I am falling flat on my backside is that I want to get out of the store, a list of People and all nodes that are connected to the person (eg their Names, DateOfBirth and Addresses) where certain conditions are met,

I have started with this:

```
MATCH (dob:DateOfBirth)-[WAS_BORN_ON]-(person:Person)-[HAS_NAME]-(name:Name) WHERE dob.Id = '1954-05-09' RETURN person, dob, name
```

And it produces something like this which is great:

[image: Full Results]

But I want to restrict it to people that have a (last) name of "williams" so I go with this

```
MATCH (dob:DateOfBirth)-[WAS_BORN_ON]-(person:Person)-[HAS_NAME]-(name:Name) WHERE dob.Id = '1954-05-09' and name.Value = 'Williams' RETURN person, dob, name"
```

Unfortunately it removes all the other names:
[image: Results with Missing Nodes]

Unfortunately I want this:

[image: Perfect World]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this would work?

```
MATCH (dob:DateOfBirth{Id: "1954-05-09"})<-[:WAS_BORN_ON]-(person:Person)
WITH dob, person
MATCH (person)-[:HAS_NAME]->(surname:Name{Value: "Williams"})
WITH person, dob
MATCH (person)-[:HAS_NAME]->(name:Name)
RETURN person, dob, name
```

**Edit**: Updated query to improve performance as suggested by ulkas.

Comment: That certainly gets the desired result, however its horrible on performance. What does work though is 
`MATCH (person:Person)-[:HAS_NAME]->(surname:Name{Value: "Williams"})
MATCH (person)-[:WAS_BORN_ON]->(dob:DateOfBirth{Id: "1954-05-09"})
MATCH (person)-[HAS_NAME]->(name:Name)
RETURN person, dob, name `

Comment: Yep, `optional match` is not ideal but I wasn't sure whether your nodes would certainly have more than one name. I've updated the answer to use only `match`. Also if you are checking properties in your where predicate Neo4j will be forced to check the property store which will also decrease performance.

Comment: no, the query is wrong. what he needs is to first pick up users based on `dob` and not `name`. why? because the performance could be terrible. you must swap the `MATCHES`: `MATCH (dob:DateOfBirth)-[WAS_BORN_ON]-(person:Person) WITH dob, person WHERE dob.Id = '1954-05-09' MATCH (person)-[HAS_NAME]-(surname:Name{Value: "Williams"}) WITH person MATCH (dob:DateOfBirth)-[WAS_BORN_ON]-(person:Person)-[HAS_NAME]-(name:Name) RETURN person, dob, name`

Answer (score 0):

I would have gone the easy route...

```
match (dob:DateOfBirth{Id: "1954-05-09"})--(p:Person)--(surname:Name{Value: "Williams"})
optional match (p)--(n:Name)
return dob, p, n
```

alternatively with a WHERE clause:

```
match (dob:DateOfBirth)--(p:Person)--(surname:Name)
optional match (p)--(n:Name)
where dob.Id = "1954-05-09" and surname.Value = "Williams"
return dob, p, n
```

But then again, I'm not the expert on performance; I focus first on simplicity.